# WS02 CAR deployment to Carbon and ESB server : No artifacts found to be deployed in this server

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I created test.car in WSO2 Developer Studio 3.5.0. CAR contains your default example SimpleStockQuoteSample. I can deploy this CAR into WS02 ESB Server 4.8.1. successfully. CAR is listed in CarbonAplication and works correctly.

When I try to deploy same CAR into SW02 Carbon Server 4.2.0, it fails on

> No artifacts found to be deployed in this server. Ignoring Carbon Application : test.car

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the Server Role for the artifacts inside your CAR is "EnterpriseServiceBus" : edit the pom.xml of your Carbon app in Dev Studio and look at Dependencies -> artifact / Server Role

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to do 2 steps:

1. Modify the wso2esb carbon.xml file in config folder.

location: {base}*wso2esb-4.9.0\repository\conf* -- **carbon.xml**
Add the ApplicationServer as role in the tag ServerRoles.

```
 <Role>ApplicationServer</Role>
```

2. Modify in your eclipse develop studio the Role of your application to ApplicationServer, this is into Dependencies->artifact and modify the Role.